# Stop and repeat process by using a timer in C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, timer

I am trying to use a timer to achieve a sort of old animation used in the past to show that a process is running.

The way I would like to do that is by adding dots to a sentence (in a label control), for example:

"Process is running." to "Process is running.." and "Process is running..." with a limit of 3 dots and then revert back to a single dot.

I am not sure as to the fact using a timer here would be the best choice, but I thought it should work fine for such a simple example.

The code I used is as follows:

```
public string InitialProcessText;

private void StartBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(fileName != "No file selected")
    {
        ValidationLbl.Text = null;
        ProcessLbl.Text = "Application is now running.";
        //InitialProcessText = ProcessLbl.Text;
        ProcessTimer.Start();
    }
    else
    {
        ValidationLbl.Text = "No file was added";
    }
}

private void StopBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessTimer.Stop();
}

private void ProcessTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _ticks++;

    //For every two ticks, ProcessLbl.Text = InitialProcessText
    ProcessLbl.Text += ".";
}
```

What could I add to set a limit of adding 2 dots and then remove the dots and add dots again (I would assume to do this in the `ProcessTimer_Tick` method)?

Comment: Where is your ProcessTimer defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use your `_ticks` variable:

```
private readonly int _ticksPerUpdate = 2;
private readonly int _maxNumberOfDots = 3;

private void ProcessTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _ticks++;

    if(_ticks == (_ticksPerUpdate * (_maxNumberOfDots + 1)))
    {
        _ticks = 0;
        ProcessLbl.Text = InitialProcessText;
    }        
    else if(_ticks % _ticksPerUpdate == 0)
    {
        ProcessLbl.Text += ".";
    }
}
```

Remember to reset the ticks counter every time you start the timer:

```
private void StartBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(fileName != "No file selected")
    {
        ValidationLbl.Text = null;
        ProcessLbl.Text = "Application is now running.";
        InitialProcessText = ProcessLbl.Text;

        // reset the variable
        _ticks = 0
        ProcessTimer.Start();
    }
    else
    {
        ValidationLbl.Text = "No file was added";
    }
}
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for, just using the ticks variable to set a limit.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that _ticks counts the number of ticks. You could then go :

```
if(ticks%3 == 0)
{
  ProcessLbl.Text = "Application is now running."
}
else
{
  ProcessLbl.Text+=".";
}
```

Then, at 1st tick, 1%3=1 so it adds a dot, at 2nd tick, 2%3=2 so it adds a dot and 3rd tick, 3%3=0, so it gets back to original.

Answer (score 1):

Just because...here's another approach:

```
private void ProcessTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessLbl.Text = ProcessLbl.Text.EndsWith("...") ? ProcessLbl.Text.TrimEnd(".".ToCharArray()) + "." : ProcessLbl.Text + ".";
}
```